# How to use source files but not built files in a local module in development environment

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack

I have a VUE project and a local library(pure Typescript)

Currently every time I modify the library I have to terminate the VUE Server, build the library, and then restart the VUE Server.

Could I change some setting to let VUE use the source ts files of the library in development environment and use the built js files in product environment? So that I can keep starting the VUE Server when I doing some modifications in the library.

Comment: This might help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-hot-reload-loader#usage (you'll need to include the path to your lib in the `include` array). Haven't tested it but should work.